# How can I set an app script on a Google Sheet via the API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

Is there a way to set an App Script on a new Google Sheet via the Google Sheets API? We use [pygsheets](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as our Python API Client for Google Sheets. Since we are using the `onSelectionChange` trigger to populate certain cells with a date, we would like to setup the app script *after* we have populated rows in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Sheets API doesn't have a method to do this. You can use the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-projects) instead, but there are a few caveats which may or may not work with your use case:

- You can use [`projects.create`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) to create a new Apps Script project and attach it to a Sheets file by specifying the `parentId` field, which is the Sheet's ID. However, there are no methods to attach a preexisting script to a Sheet. You can still use [`projects.updateContent`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) to add the required script files, though.
- You [cannot unbind](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) the script once it has been attached.
- This API [does not work](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts) with service accounts, and the user running it needs to explicitly [allow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable) it in their [settings](https://script.google.com/home/usersettings) page. This is for security reasons, since allowing a malicious app to freely write scripts on your account could be catastrophic, but it adds more steps that your users would need to take in order to run your app.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `You cannot unbind the script once it has been attached.`?

Comment: Just that you cannot separate a script from a Sheet to make it standalone as mentioned in the article linked. You can delete it though, just not separate it. Not sure how relevant it would be to the OP but I mentioned it as one of the caveats.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood about `You cannot unbind the script once it has been attached.`.